# Arrow keys not working properly during rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rbenv, pry

During development phase of my rails app, I need to use `rails console` command. In this command, I also need to modify my commands like navigating around my command, calling previous command to console, etc. But after pressing arrow keys, it instead of calls letters like `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` -and it processes these letters as command, and naturally it gives error.-

In addition, I've faced this issue on Ubuntu with Ruby 2.0.0 with rbenv. In my Gemfile, gems like `pry-rails`, `rb-readline`('~> 0.4.2') are defined.

NEW 1: Here's error ouput before exit from `rails console`:

```
FATAL: Pry failed to get user input using `Readline`.
To fix this you may be able to pass input and output file descriptors to pry directly. e.g.
  Pry.config.input = STDIN
  Pry.config.output = STDOUT
  binding.pry
```

NEW 2: I run `rails console` on `bash` & I also removed `pry-rails` from  `Gemfile` but the problem still happens.

Comment: Yes, nowadays I'm with zsh

Comment: I've encountered that issue several times on zsh, try temporarily switching to bash (or any other shell) and checking it since there was too many causes (mostly it was caused by color-adding aliases) so we will remove that branch if it's not that.

Comment: @zrl3dx I'm waiting forward to fix of the issue.

Comment: So try running `rails c` in bash so we will know are we on a good track or not ;) You may try running first `set term=builtin_ansi`, that shouldn't break anything but may help.

Comment: Nope, it didn't work, too :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37368/discussion-between-zrl3dx-and-ekremkrc)

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue with the fish shell and bash.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the gem [pry-rails](http://rubygems.org/gems/pry-rails)?

That works fine for my projects.

Comment: It was `pry-rails` in my Gemfile, but I wrote `pry` unexpectedly. Sorry about that :(

Comment: :) did you try to install readline with apt-get? Because the readline ruby-lib is just a wrapper for that. Which package i explicit installed i dont know :)

maybe also with *-dev?!

Comment: I have `libreadline6`, `rlwrap` & `readline-common` installed.

Comment: Installed but not worked, I also updated question, it's good to check.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue,

I removed the gem `rb-readline` and it was solved!

Answer (score 0):

Per @ekremkaraca I installed all the libs specified

```
sudo apt-get install -y libreadline6 rlwrap readline-common libreadline6-dev
```

Then I recompiled Ruby to make use of those libraries:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.1/ruby-2.1.5.tar.gz
tar xzf ruby-2.1.5.tar.gz
cd ruby-2.1.5
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Now my Ruby instance (irb, etc) recognizes up/down/left/right arrows and related keys.

Note if you use rvm (or rbenv, etc) to manage Ruby then don't use my instructions for compiling - follow your manager's instructions!